# Typeform in Ionic App causes zone.js failure

Tags: ionic-framework, zone.js, typeform

I have an Ionic app (runs Angular 4) and in one view I'd like to embed a typeform using the [typeform embed sdk](https://developer.typeform.com/embed/).  For some reason adding the following code results in a zone error:

```
Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.
Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)
```

To make things simple I started a [new app in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-cgbs3m?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts) and it shows the same error.  The relevant code is as follows:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  let el = this.typeform.nativeElement;

    typeformEmbed.makeWidget(
      el,
      'https://developerplatform.typeform.com/to/Xc7NMh', // NOTE: Replace with your typeform URL
      {
        hideHeaders: true,
        hideFooter: true,
        opacity: 75,
        buttonText: "Take the survey!",
        onSubmit: function () {
          console.log('Typeform successfully submitted')
        }
      }
    )
}
```

Any ideas why I am seeing this error before the app even loads?

Answer (score 0):

Try version 0.7.1: `npm install --save @typeform/embed@0.7.1`